# Repetir LEFT JOIN com outros parâmetros na mesma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Tenho 2 tabelas:

PAI:

```
id
nome
```

FILHO:

```
id
idpai
sexo_filho
```

Queria fazer um SELECT que soma a quantidade de filhos homem e mulheres, aí que está o problema, eu só consigo fazer com um dos sexo:

```
SELECT pai.nome, count(distinct filho.id) as somahomem 
FROM pai 
LEFT JOIN filho ON pai.id = filho.idpai AND conta_filho.sexo = 'm'
```

Como fazer com os dois sexos? Ter o valor dos dois?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) para contabilizar apenas uma condição. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
 SELECT
          PAI.NOME,
          COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN FILHO.SEXO = 'F' THEN FILHO.ID ELSE NULL END)) AS 'FEMININO',
          COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN FILHO.SEXO = 'M' THEN FILHO.ID ELSE NULL END)) AS 'MASCULINO'
 FROM
          PAI
          LEFT JOIN FILHO ON FILHO.ID_PAI = PAI.ID
 GROUP BY
          PAI.NOME
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa7699/2)

Comment: Valeu, ta indo certinho, não tem como colocar um distinct nele?

Comment: Nessa estrutura que você informou, ao meu ver, é desnecessário o distinct pois o resultado seria o mesmo.

Comment: Então, minha consulta é mais complexa, tem vários count e sum com outras tabelas.

Sem o distict não sei porque ele vai multiplcando os counts entre eles....

Comment: Atualizei com o DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar mais de um `JOIN`:

```
SELECT pai.nome, 
    count(distinct filho.id) as somahomem,
    count(distinct filho2.id) as somamulher
FROM pai 
    LEFT JOIN filho ON pai.id = filho.idpai AND filho.sexo = 'm'
    LEFT JOIN filho2 ON pai.id = filho2.idpai AND filho2.sexo = 'f'
GROUP BY 
    pai.nome;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar o `SUM()` com `IF()`

```
SELECT 
  pai.nome, 
  SUM(if(filho.sexo = 'm', 1, 0)) as somahomem,
  SUM(if(filho.sexo = 'f', 1, 0)) as somamulher
FROM 
  pai 
  LEFT JOIN filho ON (pai.id = filho.idpai)
GROUP BY pai.id
```